# Interpretar o comando MySQL Explain

Tags: mysql, otimização

Tenho uma query que está a demorar 6/8 segundos para executar.

A base de dados que estou a usar é MySQL.

No PhpMyAdmin fiz o seguinte:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id_categoria, sc.categoria, categoria_principal, associada FROM 
get_produto_categoria gpc INNER JOIN shop_categoria sc USING(id_categoria) WHERE
gpc.id_produto = 2254 ORDER BY categoria_principal DESC, associada DESC, sc.ord ASC,
sc.id_categoria ASC
```

Veja abaixo o resultado da query:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sempre fiz optimizações utilizando apenas tabelas, porém a query acima utiliza uma view (get_produto_categoria).

1. Não consigo entender a primeira linha, onde diz "Table: derived2 / Rows:23248".
2. Como seria a interpretação do resultado acima levando em conta que estou a utilizar um View.

Answer (score 3):

Na documentação online do MySQL podes encontrar a explicação para todos os aspetos presentes na explicação [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>.

## derivedN

Referente à tua duvida em particular, podemos [ler aqui](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html#explain_table) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>:

> The name of the table to which the row of output refers. This can also be one of the following values:
>
> `<unionM,N>`: The row refers to the union of the rows with id values of M and N.
>
> `<derivedN>`: The row refers to the derived table result for the row with an id value of N. A derived table may result, for example, from a subquery in the FROM clause.

Que traduzido:

> O nome da tabela para a qual a linha de saída se refere. Isto também pode ser um dos seguintes valores:
>
> `<unionM,N>`: A linha se refere à união das linhas com valores de ID de M e N.
>
> `<derivedN>`: A linha refere-se ao resultado tabela derivada para a linha com um valor de identificação de N. A tabela derivada pode resultar, por exemplo, de uma subconsulta na cláusula FROM.

O teu resultado atual `derived2` indica que a linha resulta da tua tabela derivada `shop_categoria` referente ao ID #2.

## rows

A segunda parte da tua duvida, podemos [ler aqui](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html#explain_rows) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>:

> The rows column indicates the number of rows MySQL believes it must examine to execute the query.

Que traduzido:

> A coluna *rows* indica o número de linhas que o MySQL acha que deve examinar para executar a consulta.

No teu caso, o MySQL acha que deve examinar 23248 linhas para chegar ao resultado.

Comment: Certo, porém não consigo chegar a uma solução para optimizar a consulta com base na informação acima. Estou a usar uma view, porém não aceita índices. O que tenho que fazer para optimizar a consulta?

Comment: @Filipe Para ajudar com essa questão só vendo as tabelas e a indexação de cada uma. A tua _view_ vai gerar os dados em tempo real sempre que acedes à mesma. A demora não é da _view_ em si mas sim das tabelas que a mesma consulta. O mais comum é estarem a ser realizadas pesquisas e/ou chaves de relação em campos não indexados.

Comment: Certo, mas de acordo com a imagem que postei sobre o resultado do explain, estão a ser utilizados campos indexados, ou estou errado?

Comment: Eu acho que `derived2` se refere justamente à view, e buscar todas as 23248 linhas dela deve estar causando a lentidão. Pode ser o caso de materializar a view numa tabela, ou usar o MariaDB, que tem suporte nativo a *materialized views*.

Comment: @Filipe De acordo com o teu `EXPLAIN` a 2ª linha a contar de baixo é problemática porque o MySQL não encontrou nenhuma indexação proveitosa. [Ver mais aqui](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information). Mas sem saber a estrutura das tabelas é difícil afirmar a origem do problema. Basta executares: `DESCRIBE nomeTabela`, tirar uma captura de tela e meter na tua pergunta.